# ViewModel base class supporting property notification, error notification and property value history

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, properties

I've created a general purpose ViewModel base class in what I believe it's purest
behaviour. It features property notification, error notification and property value history. Please take a look at it and tell me what can be improved or what
you think is missing.

For the sake of clarity I've merged everything in 1 codeblock:

```
namespace Trakt
{
    [System.AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, Inherited = false, AllowMultiple = false)]
    public sealed class TrackedAttribute : Attribute
    {
        public TrackedAttribute() { }
    }

    public abstract class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged, INotifyDataErrorInfo
    {
        private const int MAXHISTORY = 10;

        private bool dirty;
        public bool Dirty
        {
            get { return dirty; }
            protected set { SetProperty(ref dirty, value); }
        }

        private bool corrupted;
        public bool Corrupted
        {
            get { return corrupted; }
            private set { SetProperty(ref corrupted, value); }
        }

        private readonly Guid _guid;
        private Stack<string> _changeList;
        private Dictionary<string, Stack<object>> _changes;
        private Dictionary<string, List<string>> _errors;

        public void ClearHistory()
        {
            _changeList = new Stack<string>();
            _changes = _changes
                .Select(_change => new KeyValuePair<string, Stack<object>>(_change.Key, new Stack<object>(new object[] { _change.Value.Pop() })))
                .ToDictionary(_change => _change.Key, _change => _change.Value);
        }

        public void ClearHistoryFor([CallerMemberName]string propertyName = "")
        {
            var lastValue = _changes[propertyName].Pop();

            _changeList = new Stack<string>(_changeList.Where(i => i != propertyName)); // changelist order still ok???
            _changes = _changes
                .Where(_change => _change.Key != propertyName)
                .Select(_change => new KeyValuePair<string, Stack<object>>(_change.Key, _change.Value))
                .ToDictionary(_change => _change.Key, _change => _change.Value);
        }

        public void ClearHistoryFor<TProperty>(Expression<Func<TProperty>> propertyExpression)
        {
            ClearHistoryFor(ExtractPropertyNameFor(propertyExpression));
        }

        protected ViewModelBase()
        {
            _guid = Guid.NewGuid();
            _changes = new Dictionary<string, Stack<object>>();
            _changeList = new Stack<string>();
            _errors = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();

            var properties = from property in this.GetType().GetProperties()
                             where Attribute.IsDefined(property, typeof(TrackedAttribute))
                             select property;

            foreach (var property in properties)
            {
                //var trakt = property.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(TrackedAttribute), true);
                var value = this.GetType().GetProperty(property.Name).GetValue(this);

                _changes.Add(property.Name, new Stack<object>(new object[] { value }));
            }
        }

        public void Undo(int steps)
        {
            var count = _changes[_changeList.Peek()].Count;

            if (count <= 1)
                return;

            if (steps >= count)
                steps = count -1;

            var lastPropertyName = _changeList.Pop();
            var previousPropertyValue = _changes[lastPropertyName].Peek();

            int i = 0;

            do
            {
                previousPropertyValue = _changes[lastPropertyName].Pop();

                i++;
            } while (i <= steps);

            SetProperty(lastPropertyName, previousPropertyValue);
        }

        public void Undo()
        {
            Undo(1);            
        }

        protected bool IsTracked<TProperty>([CallerMemberName]string propertyName = "")
        {
            return _changes.ContainsKey(propertyName);
        }

        protected void Track<TProperty>([CallerMemberName]string propertyName = "")
        {
            Track(default(TProperty), propertyName);
        }

        protected void Track<TProperty>(TProperty value, [CallerMemberName]string propertyName = "")
        {
            if (_changes.ContainsKey(propertyName))
                return;

            if (!this.GetType().GetProperties().Select(p => p.Name).Contains(propertyName))
                return;

            _changes.Add(propertyName, new Stack<object>(new object[] { value }));
        }

        protected void UnTrack<TProperty>([CallerMemberName]string propertyName = "")
        {
            if (!_changes.ContainsKey(propertyName))
                return;

            _changes.Remove(propertyName);
        }

        #region INotifyDataErrorInfo
        public bool HasErrors { get { return Corrupted; } }

        public event EventHandler<DataErrorsChangedEventArgs> ErrorsChanged;

        private void OnErrorsChanged([CallerMemberName]string propertyName = "")
        {
            var handler = ErrorsChanged;
            handler?.Invoke(this, new DataErrorsChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        public IEnumerable GetErrors()
        {
            // TODO!
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public IEnumerable GetErrors<TProperty>(Expression<Func<TProperty>> propertyExpression)
        {
            return GetErrors(ExtractPropertyNameFor(propertyExpression));
        }

        public IEnumerable GetErrors([CallerMemberName]string propertyName = "")
        {
            var errors = new List<string>();
            _errors.TryGetValue(propertyName, out errors);

            return errors;
        }

        protected void AddError(string errorMessage, [CallerMemberName]string propertyName = "")
        {
            if (!_errors.ContainsKey(propertyName))
                _errors.Add(propertyName, new List<string>());

            _errors[propertyName].Add(errorMessage);
            OnErrorsChanged(propertyName);

            Corrupted = true;
        }

        protected void ClearError([CallerMemberName]string propertyName = "")
        {
            _errors.Remove(propertyName);
            OnErrorsChanged(propertyName);

            Corrupted = _errors.Select(e => e.Value).Count() != 0;
        }

        protected bool HasError([CallerMemberName]string propertyName = "")
        {
            return _errors.ContainsKey(propertyName) && _errors[propertyName].Count > 0;
        }
        #endregion

        #region INotifyPropertyChanged
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string propertyName = "")
        {
            var handler = PropertyChanged;
            handler?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        protected void SetProperty<TProperty>(string propertyName, TProperty value/*, bool notify = true*/)
        {
            this.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).SetValue(this, value);
        }

        protected void SetProperty<TProperty>(ref TProperty field, TProperty value, [CallerMemberName]string propertyName = "")
        {
            if (!EqualityComparer<TProperty>.Default.Equals(field, value))
            {
                field = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);

                if (_changes.ContainsKey(propertyName))
                {
                    if(_changes[propertyName].Count == MAXHISTORY)
                    {
                        // max history limit reached, need to shift items...
                        var list = new LinkedList<object>(_changes[propertyName]);
                        list.RemoveLast();

                        _changes[propertyName] = new Stack<object>(list.Reverse());
                    }

                    _changeList.Push(propertyName);
                    _changes[propertyName].Push(value);
                }

                if(propertyName != nameof(Dirty))
                    Dirty = true;
            }
        }

        protected void SetProperty<TProperty>(ref TProperty field, TProperty value, Expression<Func<TProperty>> propertyExpression)
        {
            SetProperty(ref field, value, ExtractPropertyNameFor(propertyExpression));
        }

        private static string ExtractPropertyNameFor<T>(Expression<Func<T>> propertyExpression)
        {
            var memberExp = propertyExpression.Body as MemberExpression;

            if (memberExp == null)
                throw new ArgumentException("Expression must be a MemberExpression.", "propertyExpression");

            return memberExp.Member.Name;
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Sample implementation:

```
public class SomeViewModel: ViewModelBase
{
    private int trackedProperty;
    [Tracked]public int TrackedProperty
    {
        get { return trackedProperty; }
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref trackedProperty, value, () => this.TrackedProperty);

            if (trackedProperty == 1)
                AddError("Value 1 is not allowed");
            else
                ClearError();
        }
    }
}
```

I'm very into SOLID (or try to) and clean code so don't be too gentle! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pretty cool implementation.  It's fairly clean and usable.  Just a few things standout to me:

---

In `SetProperty<TProperty>(ref TProperty field, TProperty value, [CallerMemberName]string propertyName = "")` it's a bit of a red flag to see the conversion to a `LinkedList` and then back to a `Stack<T>` in order to pop the first item at the 'bottom' of the `Stack<T>`.  `Stack<T>` isn't really the ideal type of data structure if you find yourself needing to do this.  You may want to consider just using a `LinkedList<T>` instead of `Stack<T>`.

`LinkedList<T>` offers methods like `AddFirst`, `AddLast` as well as `RemoveLast` and `RemoveFirst`.  The below comments could apply to usage of a `LinkedList<T>` as well.

In the `ViewModelBase` ctor() you get back all the properties with the `TrackedAttribute` on them then add their initial values in a subsequent for loop.  For each of the properties in the `properties` enumerable you reflect on the current type to get the `PropertyInfo` object so you can get the value, but you already have the `PropertyInfo` object from the linq above it.

Changing this to `property.GetValue(this)` should save you the extra reflection call per property.

If you wanted to you should be able to eliminate the `foreach` loop entirely with a little extra linq:

```
var properties = (from property in GetType().GetProperties()
                              where Attribute.IsDefined(property, typeof(TrackedAttribute))
                              select property).ToDictionary(prop => prop.Name, 
                                    prop => new Stack<object>(new[] { prop.GetValue(this) }));
```

---

You might want to consider handling an empty Stack in case someone attempts to `Undo()` when the `changeList` `Stack<T>` is empty on `var count = _changes[_changeList.Peek()].Count;`.  According to [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.stack.peek(v=vs.110).aspx) an `InvalidOperationException` will be thrown when calling `Peek()` on a `Stack` with no objects on it.  I believe a possible unit test for this is calling `Undo()` once then calling it again (Call twice since each 'Tracked' object has a `Stack<T>` created with its initial value).

Additionally, changing the name of `Undo()` to something a bit more descriptive would be helpful. E.g., `UndoPrevious()` or `UndoLast()`.  This way the consumer knows right away just how much 'undoing' this method does.

---

Where is the `_guid` member used?  I see where it is created in the ctor, but not consumed.

---

Consider catching/handling the `Pop()` call for an empty `Stack` in `ClearHistoryFor()` as well (although it does not appear `lastValue` is used).

---

I'm not entirely certain what the benefit of the `Expression<Func<TProperty>> propertyExpression` overloads of `SetProperty` are over using the `CallerMemberNameAttribute` since `CallerMemberNameAttribute` will send in the name of the property for you at runtime.  Getting the property name from the `Expression<Func<T>>` is slower than from `CallerMemberNameAttribute`.  I'm assuming you are using C#5 (or 6) based on the nameof() usage to check if the property name is 'Dirty'.  [Marc Gravell details this here if interested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1316417/631417).

---

In answer to your comment/question about "changelist order still ok???" I believe it will be in order.  Here are some sources for my reasoning:  [JSkeet on preserving order with linq](https://stackoverflow.com/a/204512/631417) and [Microsoft's albeit partially vague statement on the topic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460677(v=vs.110).aspx).

Relevant section from that article (near the top):

> In PLINQ, the goal is to maximize performance while maintaining
>   correctness. A query should run as fast as possible but still produce
>   the correct results. In some cases, correctness requires the order of
>   the source sequence to be preserved; however, ordering can be
>   computationally expensive. Therefore, by default, PLINQ does not
>   preserve the order of the source sequence. In this regard, PLINQ
>   resembles LINQ to SQL, **but is unlike LINQ to Objects, which does
>   preserve ordering.**

Hope this helps!

Comment: Very helpful Jordan, I will look into this. I have already extended on the Viewmodel base class and still look to improve it so I'll take your notes in account!

Comment: I'll put this on Github when I completed the test assembly so you can collaborate if you want.